# Division Algorithm proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, proof-verification

May someone tell me if there is anything wrong with my proof? And what can I do to improve it, please?

So the theorem is

> Let a,b$\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ with b$>$0. Then $\exists$ q,r$\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ : $a=qb+r$ where $0 \leq r < b$

Now, I'm only considering the case where $b<a$.

Proof: Let $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a>b$. Assume that for $1,2,3,\dots,a-1$, the result holds. Now consider three cases: 
1) a-b=b and so setting q=1 and r=0 gives the desired result.
2) a-b$<$b and so setting q=0 and r=a-b gives the desired result.
3)$a-b>b$ and since a-b$\geq$ 1 it follows by the induction hypothesis that there exists t and r such that a-b=bt+r and so setting q=t+1 gives the desired result.

Comment: Need $b>0$ in your version.

Comment: Yes, clearly that is the case. Notice, I said 0$\leq$ r $<$ b.

Comment: It is not clearly the case, as you have only stated that $b\neq0$. In fact the statement you are proving is *false*; you claim the existence of some $r\geq0$ with $0\leq r<b$, for any nonzero $b\in\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: No, that's the thing trying to prove.

Comment: @coffeemath oh I see.

Comment: @coffeemath why do I need $b>0$ in my version?

Comment: Well if one doesn't assume that, conclusion should be $0 \le r <|b|.$

Comment: @Servaes so if I change my theorem to $b>0$, then my proof is correct?

Comment: No. You haven't considered the case $a\leq b$, though your theorem concerns *all* $a,b\in\Bbb{Z}$ with $b\neq0$ (or $b>0$?). Also, you proof seems to be by induction, but this is not mentioned anywhere and I don't see a base case.

Comment: @Servaes is a base case required for strong induction?

Comment: Give it some thought.

Comment: You are using induction. Therefore the first step is to prove the base case (here, this is $a=b+1$).

Comment: Is there a difference between $\Bbb{N}$ and $\Bbb{Z}^+\cup\{0\}$? The fact that you make explicit that $b>0$ suggests that you use the convention that $0\in\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: @Servaes May you please look at the edit, please?

Comment: I don't understand why you're reversing my MathJax edits, making the formulas completely wrong as far as math typesetting is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strong induction hypothesis is

> For every $a'$, with $b<a'<a$, there exist $t$ and $r$ such that $a'=bt+r$, with $0\le r<b$.

You have $a-b<a$, but you don't know whether $a-b>b$. However the case $a-b\le b$ is easily taken care of: in case $a-b<b$ you can set $t=0$ and $r=a-b$; in case $a-b=b$ then take $t=1$ and $r=0$. If $a-b>b$, then the strong induction hypothesis provides $t$ and $r$ with $a-b=bt+r$ and $0\le r<b$. Then you can set $q=t+1$.

On the other hand, you can simply avoid the assumption that $a>b$. The strong induction hypothesis then can be

> For every $a'<a$, there exist $q$ and $r$ such that $a'=bt+r$, with $a'=bt+r$ and $0\le r<b$.

If $a\le b$, you can do as done before. If $a>b$, then $a-b<a$ and you can use the induction hypothesis.

Comment: What about now? May you please look at my edit?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your questions about the proof you gave, but you might want to note that there's a different approach that doesn't use induction explcitly - it seems simpler to me, or at least cleaner:

Define $$R=\{r=a-qb: q\in\Bbb N, r\ge0\}.$$Taking $q=0$ shows that $R$ is nonempty. Any nonempty set of non-negative integers has a smallest element; let $r_0$ be the smallest element of $R$.

You're done if you can show that $r_0<b$. But it's easy to show this:

> > If $r_0\ge b$ then $r=r_0-b\in R$.

Since $r_0-b<r_0$ this shows that if $r_0\ge b$ then $r_0$ is not the smallest element of $R$, contradiction.

**Edit:** I've been asked why I would ocnsider that set. Hmm...

Define $r$ to be a function of $q$; $$r(q)=a-qb.$$We need to show

> > There exists $q$ suuch that $0\le r(q)<b$.

How might we try to find such a $q$? Well, it's pretty clear that if we first restrict attention to $q$ such that $r(q)\ge0$, then if there does exist a $q$ with $r(q)<b$, the smallest possible $r(q)$ must work. So we choose $q$ to minimize $r(q)$ (again, subject to the restriction that $r(q)\ge0$.

And now letting $R$ be that set and taking the smallest element of $R$ is the obvious way to show formally that there *is* a $q$ that minimizes $r(q)$.

**Note** The statement that every non-empty subset of $\Bbb N$ has a smallest element says that $\Bbb N$ is "well-ordered". The fact that $\Bbb N$ is well ordered is equivalent to the validity of proof by induction - any proof by induction has an equivalent version using well-ordering and vice-versa. Sometimes one comes out seeming simpler, sometimes the other.

**Comment:** The tags seem to indicate you're taking a course in abstract algebra. It's going to happen a lot that proofs of things involve defining a certain set and deducing properties of it. (If $G$ is a finite group and $a\in G$ then the order of $a$ divides the order of $G$: Let $S$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$...)

Comment: But why would you consider that set?

Comment: @mathsssislife The edit may or may not make this clear...